# Invalid host for SSH forwarding: ssh : Could not resolve hostname

Tags: juju, maas

Actually trying to insatll MaaS server with ubuntu 12.04 and JuJu. Once installed, tried to add a new node in mass gui. It seems WoL worked and OS was installed, the new node had been deployed and running. However, when trying juju status after bootsrapping the environement, it seems something goes wrong with the DNS server.

```
$juju status
 INFO Connecting to environment...
ERROR Invalid host for SSH forwarding: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node01: Name or service not known
```

maas-dhcp is installed and configured in the MaaS server.
No DNS service was added but use the default one (127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf file).

Chcek the `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`.

No entries for the specified node!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dnsmasq - you should have definied 'node01' inside the /etc/hosts. Is it there?

If not - try to add it:

```
192.168.1.25 node01
```

Replace ip with the correct one.

Check also:

```
ping node01
host node01
dig  node01
```

And check your files /etc/dnsmasq.conf, you can find some help here:

http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq.conf.example

Comment: thanks for the response but the problem I dont see any ip address assigned to the new node deployed ??

Comment: What do you mean? What is ip of your node01?

Comment: Node01 was deployed by maas [after adding it s maac address in maas UI]. node01 has been deployed and installed after running juju bootrap withinig the conf file. but i can't retrieve it s Ip address to add it in /etc/hosts in maas server.

Comment: What you should check - in /etc/hosts should be also your mac address for new host, like this:

    dhcp-host=4E:8C:B6:1B:AD:51,10.0.0.51

If its there - try to add manually, add some ip and restart dnsmasq

Comment: I checked the /etc/hosts and still by default. No new node ip address or mac address are being added. Even try to add it manually I should add the associated ip address which is unknown ??

Comment: Sorry, I made typo - regarding the last file it is /etc/dnsmasq.conf - i did edit inside the answer

Comment: OK I checked /ect/dnsmasq.conf file. no new entry but added the mac address of the node01. The ipaddress not known but entred one in the same dhcp range. But does not work !!!